# .Net Nest Elastic search - how to get index name with document

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest .Net client for Elasticsearch.
I am having issue with updating my document, since I don't know the elastic Id and the the index for that matter, since I am locating the document to update using AllIndices(). In order to just index the document again it seems I need at least the index name the document is indexed on.
Help anybody?

Answer (score 1):

If you can locate your document through search, then the `_index` and `_id` (and `_type`, if relevant for the version of Elasticsearch you're using) will be available on [the hits metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#_matching_documents), so you would be able to use this information to update the document with the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).